# Using Javascript to create multiple 'div'' tags with specific class name and css style code

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is what I have come up with....

```
document.body.onload = function addElement() {
  // create a new div element
  let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = 'carrierBG';
  newDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#03b7ff';
  newDiv.style.width = '400px';
  newDiv.style.height = '400px';

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById('div');
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
};
```

it creates a div tag in my html file...

```
<div class="carrierBG" style="background-color: rgb(3, 183, 255); width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

How do i replicate this so all of the code is in the same javascript file and I can create additional 'div' tags with different classnames and css style code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function with the parameters you want to add:

```js
document.body.onload = function addElement() {
  // Add generated elements to the DOM
  var body = null;

  createAndAdd("div", "blue", body); // Call this once
  createAndAdd("div", "red", body);  // Call this twice
  createAndAdd("div", "green", body);// Call this thrice
  createAndAdd("div", "blue", body); // Call this as many times as a new element is wanted
  createAndAdd("div", "red", body);
  createAndAdd("div", "green", body);
  createAndAdd("div", "blue", body);
  createAndAdd("div", "red", body);
  createAndAdd("div", "green", body);
};

// Insert an element with a class name before the passed element
function createAndAdd(tag, className, placeBefore) {
  let element = createElement(tag, className);
  document.body.insertBefore(element, placeBefore);
}

// Return a new element with a certain class
function createElement(tag, className) {
   let element = document.createElement(tag);
   element.className = className;
   return element;
}
```

```css
div.blue {
  background-color: #03b7ff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

div.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

div.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

I also suggest creating a class for the styles wanted, instead of adding them through JS.

By the way, `getElementById('div')` is returning `null` in your case (because there is no `div` when the page loads), which just happens to append an item to the body. So that's what I did with the script above.

Comment: Thanks this is working! So unfortunately the file I am sending to another developer needs to have all the css style coding done in the javascript file (nirmally I would do it in a separate css file). How would I add style coding to this code you just sent me?

Comment: @ChadKirkendall Hadn't you just done it in your example? `element.style.backgroundColor = '#03b7ff';` etc?

Comment: @ChadKirkendall Please accept/upvote the answer if it solved your problem, or explain why it does not provide the answer to your question.

Comment: So your code is working perfectly but now need to insert a canvas tag (with id) inside one of the div's I'm creating. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @ChadKirkendall Create a new function, patterned after `createElement()` that creates an element and sets `element.id` instead of `element.className`. Then call the function `functionYouMake("canvas", "id-name")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an anonymous function as `onload` event listener. In this function you can do whatever you want. For example.

```js
// declare function first
function addElement(){...}
document.body.onload = () => new Array(100).fill(true).forEach(addElement)

// or use use anonymous function
document.body.onload = () => new Array(100).fill(true).forEach(() => {
  // code to add elements here
})
```

I initialize a new array of size 100 and fill it with bits. Then I call the `addElement` function for each item (100 times).

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there with the `addElement` function since it does everything you're wanting to do, but in a hardcoded fashion. The gist of the solution is that you'll want to add parameters to `addElement` for the class name and styles.

This means your `addElement` function will end up looking more like:

```
function addElement(className, styles) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add(className);

  // set your styles here, maybe doing something like
  Object.assign(newDiv.style, styles);
}
```

You'll want to be aware that using `Object.assign` would require a polyfill for IE11 but since you're using `let` your project might already have common functions like that polyfilled or IE11 support doesn't matter. It would most likely be easier to maintain long term if your class handled the styling via CSS.

Finally, instead of using `addElement` as the callback to the `onload` event, you'll want to pass it inside the body of another function.

```
document.body.onload = function handleOnload() {
  addElement('className1', { color: 'green' });
  addElement('className2', { color: '#000', 'background': 'orange' });
}
```

Comment: So this did not work. I copied and pasted this into my external javascript file that I have linked in my html file and its not producing any div tags in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `addElement` to `document.body.onload`, you could do something like this:

```
function addElement() {
  // ...
}
document.body.onload = function () {
  addElement(/* first element */);
  addElement(/* second element */);
}
```